# Astyanax retrieve by UUID

Tags: cassandra, uuid, astyanax

How do we retrieve a row in Cassandra using Astyanax?

I have a web application which requires pagination to be done on the server side, the db is cassandra. The row key is a UUID and I have few columns within a row, so I am trying to do pagination on the row keys.

I have put together a solution with which i am not completely happy. The issue is that when i do my first search based on the search filter i get from UI, I don't know the UUID of the first row, So I prepare a Query which gives me first 6 records, I store the key of the 6th record in a MAP and put it in a session, so when user from UI request for a second page, i retrieve this key(UUID) and take it as a start for the next set of records to be retrieved. I was trying to find a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT in response to question changes...

In that case, sounds like you are doing it just fine.  Also sounds like you are using OOP then as otherwise the rows are not in order.  While playOrm's solution is more elegant returning you a cursor that you store in the session, I think what you have is just fine.

EDIT since our code changed
line 74 in this link is how we do it(you can drill down into that cursor class basically to see what we do).

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alvazan/orm/layer9z/spi/db/cassandra/CassandraSession.java

which if you have 10 row keys you just pass in the list of keys.

I am not sure what you mean by pagination????  Are you saying you have a from and to row key and want the rows between them?  Are you using order the cluster by row key then?

Another completely different direction to go for ordering is playOrm though which can do S-SQL and if things are partitioned, you can do joins and other such(that link above is to one of the files in playOrm actually).

I am really not sure what you mean "you don't have the row key with you"

later,
Dean

Comment: thanks for the reply. Let me put it in a better way. Its a web application which has a search page, user enters a value lets say a filed with name value, for example name="xyz", now I want to get only first 5 records matching the criteria and when user go to page 2 on UI, i get the next 5 records. Basic Pagination.....